# Nombre de los clientes que han comprado todos los productos de la empresa MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Buenas noches estoy realizando la siguiente consulta en MySQL pero no he conseguido lograrlo, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho

```
select nombre from clientes where num_cliente in (select num_cliente from factura where num_factura in (select num_factura from venta where cod_producto in (select cod_producto from producto)))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Tiene que hacer `JOIN` de las tablas relacionadas y contar los códigos únicos de la tabla de productos de la empresa (por aparte esta es la única que no va `join`), luego contar si la union de todos los códigos de productos únicos (`distinct`) de todas las facturas agrupadas `GROUP BY` por el cliente totalizan la misma cantidad de códigos únicos (`distinct`) de productos que la empresa tiene usando el `HAVING`.

El query queda así:

```
SELECT distinct C.nombre, C.num_cliente
FROM factura as F
JOIN venta as V ON V.num_factura = F.num_factura
JOIN clientes as C ON C.num_cliente = F.num_cliente
GROUP BY C.num_cliente
HAVING count(distinct V.cod_producto) = (SELECT distinct count(cod_producto) as total FROM producto)
```

Comment: ¿Crees o estás seguro? Por favor leer [answer]. Responder sólo con código, sin dar una explicación medianamente aceptable, se considera de baja calidad. Saludos

Comment: Completado el ajuste de explicado del query.